# Mysql Enterprise Encryption / Backup & Restore

Tags: mysql

To use the Encryption in MySql I would require the Enterprise version (TDE). (Unless I am mistaken?!?).

The cost for this is quite high, and the information about it is not really helpful.

I have a question and hope someone can help me.

When using Encryption and making backups. Can those backups only be restored on the same machine (special backup software) or is it possible to dump the databases, copy to a remove server and in case of emergency restore them (with the backup-ed key files as well of course).